# Как получить высоту заголовка колонны в dataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Ситуация такая. Есть dataGridView, в котором названия колонн прописываются программно. Так же прописан перенос по строкам:

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

Проблема в том, что при попытке получить высоту заголовков колонн с помощью ColumnHeadersHeight, я получаю исходное значение этого свойства, а не действительную высоту, которая поменялась после заполнения заголовков текстом.
Можно ли как то получить актуальную высоту заголовков колонн?